# UITableview doesn't scroll to content offset on ViewDidLoad when In-Call status bar is showing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, autosize

I created an view controller containing a UITableView that needs to scroll to the bottom before the view is shown. Which I did like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [self scrollToBottom];
}

-(void)scrollToBottom {
    [self.mytable setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 100000)];
}
```

This works fine ... unless the in-call status bar is showing (which resizes the tableview in question due to a Autosizing mask on the height of the view.